# A way to append an img with multiple attributes in a single statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to append an image in a div using jQuery with multiple attributes at once.

To do so I've tried this :

```
function getImage() {
    $('wrapper').append($('<img />').attr( { src:"image.jpg", alt:"Test2" } ));
}
```

```js
function getImage() {
    $('wrapper').append($('<img />').attr( { src:"image.jpg", alt:"Test2" } ));
}

getImage();
console.log($('wrapper').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<wrapper>
</wrapper>
```

It seems it doesn't work at all.
So I've done it with two statements like that :

```
$('#wrapper').append($('<img />').attr("id", "img"));
$("#img").attr( { src:"image.jpg", alt:"Test2" } );
```

Yet I don't know why it doesn't work using just one statement.
I've tried debugging this and found that appending an image with one attribute only works just fine.

```
$('#wrapper').append($('<img />').attr("src", "image.jpg"));
```

No error messages whatsoever, just nothing happens with the piece of code including multiple attributes at once.
Did I miss something ? Thanks.

Comment: Your first code works just fine for me, see snippet

Comment: damn I'm so idiot, I did a typo on my code and somehow managed to correct it here online while cleaning my function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('#wrapper').append('<img id="img" src="image.jpg" alt="Test2">');
// Or
$('#wrapper').append('<img id="img">');
$('#img').attr('alt','Test2');
```

I will advice you to read the documentation of jquery append and attr functions

Comment: I did so a couple of times, the synthax showed on the doc isn't the one you provided.
I really wanted to use the attr method.